# Laravel Sail container suddenly unreachable

Tags: php, laravel, docker, docker-compose, laravel-sail

A few days ago my sail environment was working just fine. Now it isn't. Currently I'm using Laravel to refactor a bunch of api's over from our legacy system. So the way it works is our legacy system makes an http request, using Guzzle, to Laravel which does the processing and then returns. I noticed on my local machine I am no longer able to hit my laravel project. I get an error of connection refused. I also noticed I'm not able to hit the application through my chrome browser either and I get **ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE**, however, if I log into any of my other containers on the same network and try to ping my laravel container it works just fine. I'd also like to note I have a **rabbitmq** service in the same **docker-compose.yml** and I'm able to hit the ui portion of that just fine in my browser.

This is a shared project being used on both Mac and Windows. The one mac machine it's running on is fine. My windows machine is the only one that's experiencing this issue. Below is an image of the output from **sail up -d**

[sail up -d output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zVJHJ.jpg)

See **laravel.test Error**??? That's never come up before. Also notice how the DockerFile is running on **CACHED** commands. Not sure if that's an issue, but it never did that before when building from scratch.

Current Configuration:

- Windows 10
- Docker Desktop 4.8.2
- PHP 8.1
- WSL2

Things I've tried (stupid or not)

- Restart my machine
- Add **php_flag opcache.enable Off** to my **.htaccess**
- Add **memory_limit = 1024M** to my **php.ini**
- Point to a different DockerFile
- Change the port
- Wipe all associate images and rebuild from scratch

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
    laravel.test:
        build:
            context: ./docker_config/sail/runtimes/8.1
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
            args:
                WWWGROUP: '${WWWGROUP}'
        image: sail-8.1/app
        extra_hosts:
            - 'host.docker.internal:host-gateway'
        ports:
            - '${APP_PORT:-80}:80'
        environment:
            WWWUSER: '${WWWUSER}'
            LARAVEL_SAIL: 1
            XDEBUG_MODE: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_MODE:-off}'
            XDEBUG_CONFIG: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_CONFIG:-client_host=host.docker.internal}'
        volumes:
            - '.:/var/www/html'
        networks:
            - sail
            - default
        depends_on:
            - rabbitmq3
    rabbitmq3:
        container_name: "rabbitmq"
        image: rabbitmq:3-management
        environment:
            - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=guest
            - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=guest
        volumes:
            - ./docker_config/rabbitmq_init/rabbitmq.conf:/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf:ro
            - ./docker_config/rabbitmq_init/definitions.json:/etc/rabbitmq/definitions.json:ro
        ports:
            # AMQP protocol port
            - '5672:5672'
            # HTTP management UI
            - '15672:15672'
networks:
    default:
        external: true
        name: localdevstructure_default
    sail:
        driver: bridge
```

DockerFile:

```
FROM ubuntu:21.10

LABEL maintainer="Taylor Otwell"

ARG WWWGROUP
ARG NODE_VERSION=16

WORKDIR /var/www/html

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
ENV TZ=UTC

RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y gnupg gosu curl ca-certificates zip unzip git supervisor sqlite3 libcap2-bin libpng-dev python2 \
    && mkdir -p ~/.gnupg \
    && chmod 600 ~/.gnupg \
    && echo "disable-ipv6" >> ~/.gnupg/dirmngr.conf \
    && apt-key adv --homedir ~/.gnupg --keyserver hkps://keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 14AA40EC0831756756D7F66C4F4EA0AAE5267A6C \
    && echo "deb https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu impish main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ppa_ondrej_php.list \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y php8.1-cli php8.1-dev \
       php8.1-pgsql php8.1-sqlite3 php8.1-gd \
       php8.1-curl \
       php8.1-imap php8.1-mysql php8.1-mbstring \
       php8.1-xml php8.1-zip php8.1-bcmath php8.1-soap \
       php8.1-intl php8.1-readline \
       php8.1-ldap \
       php8.1-msgpack php8.1-igbinary php8.1-redis php8.1-swoole \
       php8.1-memcached php8.1-pcov php8.1-xdebug \
    && php -r "readfile('https://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php -- --install-dir=/usr/bin/ --filename=composer \
    && curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_$NODE_VERSION.x | bash - \
    && apt-get install -y nodejs \
    && npm install -g npm \
    && curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add - \
    && echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y yarn \
    && apt-get install -y mysql-client \
    && apt-get install -y postgresql-client \
    && apt-get install -y vim \
    && apt-get -y autoremove \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

RUN setcap "cap_net_bind_service=+ep" /usr/bin/php8.1

RUN groupadd --force -g $WWWGROUP sail
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash --no-user-group -g $WWWGROUP -u 1337 sail

COPY start-container /usr/local/bin/start-container
COPY supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf
COPY highPriority-worker.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/highPriority-worker.conf
COPY lowPriority-worker.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/lowPriority-worker.conf
COPY php.ini /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/99-sail.ini
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/start-container

EXPOSE 8000

ENTRYPOINT ["start-container"]
```

EDIT:

The only error I keep coming across is this:

"Error response from daemon: Get "https://sail-8.1/v2/": Failed to lookup host: sail-8.1"

I believe this relates to the error shown in the provided image for service laravel.test. What's happening is that service enters the "Pulling" stage and within a second errors out. So this is leading me to believe that something is happening during image creation

Comment: [Does this work?](https://github.com/laravel/sail/issues/263#:~:text=Description%3A%20Sail%20command%20is%20now%20broken%20even%20just,a%20named%2C%20running%20service%20in%20your%20docker-compose.yml%20file.)

Comment: @Jaquarh There doesn't really appear to be an approved answer there, but I did try out what was listed there with no success. As mentioned this isn't a new laravel project build. just a new build of the image in my docker environment. Should be as simple as cloning the project, installing my composer dependencies and sail up -d. As soon as I run sail up -d it errors out laravel.test service. What would be really nice is if there was some kind of verbose option on the sail up command to get more information on the error

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out what was happening and this was really stupid on my part. I thought that inherently supervisor isn't setup to autostart on local dev environments, but when using sail it is. In the supervisord.conf file that gets copied over to the container from local, there's a program in there to run the artisan serve command. Long story short I commented this out thinking it wasn't necessary. Didn't realize sail was using supervisor to keep that command running.